# Is there an equivalent in ggplot to the varwidth option in plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am creating boxplots using ggplot and would like to represent the sample size contributing to each box.  In the base `plot` function there is the `varwidth` option.  Does it have an equivalent in ggplot?

For example, in base plot

```
data <- data.frame(rbind(cbind(rnorm(700, 0,10), rep("1",700)),
                         cbind(rnorm(50, 0,10), rep("2",50))))
data[ ,1] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,1]))
plot(data[,1] ~ as.factor(data[,2]), varwidth = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I seem to recall someone asking this on the mailing list quite a while ago and they were told it wasn't possible. I don't see anything referencing this in the issues on github, so it might still not be possible. (An alternative is to use fill colors.)

Comment: Not possible with ggplot, if you're only generating one plot you could possibly modify it in Illustrator or something similar

Comment: @joran I have learnt from bitter experience that calling anything in R impossible just serves as bait for someone to prove you wrong. In this case the migthy @ kohske provided a workaround.

Comment: How many points do you have per boxplot?

Comment: This has now been implemented with the `varwidth` argument.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25171210/3897439

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not elegant but you can do that by:

```
data <- data.frame(rbind(cbind(rnorm(700, 0,10), rep("1",700)),
                         cbind(rnorm(50, 0,10), rep("2",50))))
data[ ,1] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,1]))
w <- sqrt(table(data$X2)/nrow(data))
ggplot(NULL, aes(factor(X2), X1)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = w[1], data = subset(data, X2 == 1)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = w[2], data = subset(data, X2 == 2))
```

[image]

If you have several levels for `X2`, then you can do without hardcoding all levels:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(factor(X2), X1)) + 
  llply(unique(data$X2), function(i) geom_boxplot(width = w[i], data = subset(data, X2 == i)))
```

Also you can post a feature request:
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues

Answer (score 2):

The current versions of [`ggplot2` (V 2.1.0)](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/geom_boxplot.html) now contains a `varwidth` option:

```
data <- data.frame(rbind(cbind(rnorm(700, 0,10), rep("1",700)),
                     cbind(rnorm(50, 0,10), rep("2",50))))
data$X1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$X1))
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X2, y = X1)) + 
    geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE)
```

[image: Example output plot from ggplot2]