# histogram with varying bin widths

Tags: r, histogram, bins

I am trying to replicate the concept of chart Fig 1 from the following paper (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.envsci.2011.08.004):

[image]

It is a histogram whose bin widths vary dependent upon the value of `x` and whose height depends on variable `y`.  The precise values in the chart are not of concern - rather, understanding how to reproduce it.

The following code creates a data frame with two characteristics (`abatement` and `cost`) for each `measure`.  the width of `measure` is the abatement, and the height of `measure` is cost.  The `measure` should be ordered from least cost to highest cost.

```
measure <- c(LETTERS)
abatement <- c(sample(1:100, 26))
cost <- c(sample(-100:250, 26))
data <- data.frame(cbind(measure, abatement, cost))
```

Comment: Here is an SO question regarding how to make boxplots have variable widths.  Perhaps it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647774/is-there-an-equivalent-in-ggplot-to-the-varwidth-option-in-plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, this is a barplot and not a histogram (histograms specifically refer to barplots used to represent binned frequencies of continuous variables) ...

Your `cbind()` is messing things up (converting `abatement` and `cost` to factors):

```
data <- data.frame(measure, abatement, cost)
```

Here's a start:

```
with(dplyr::arrange(data,cost),
     barplot(width=abatement,height=cost,space=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand well what the question is, but if you are looking for ordering the data frame I think that this could be a good solution:

```
data2 <- data[ order(cost), ]
```

Or you can use `dplyr` package and its `arrange` function.

Comment: As I read it, OP wants the widths of the bars to vary according to abatement, not to order the bars.